# TCDL tags not appearing in Broker database

Tags: broker, tcdl, component

Our requirement is to get Component Content dynamically.I am using Tridion SP1 2013. Instead of using the static content of embedded component i want to get the content of embedded component dynamically.

Let me give you better clear picture of it.

[image]

Under Content node we have created tcdl tags and able to see the xml in preview as well as in template builder.When we are publishing the component, we are not able to get the same information in Broker database.
We decoded Content Xml from Component Presentation table using LINQPad but tcdl tags are not appearing.I am using Publication Target Language as 'REL'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is in a dynamic Component Template, what is the output format of that CT?

Comment: Yes I am using Dynamic CT. Output format is HTML fragment.

Comment: Try changing that format to REL. CT output format overrides Publication Target setting

Comment: Now when I am accessing the dynamic component content via Content Service API's, it is not fecthing Content from component, instead it is showing tcdl tags only.

Comment: Please edit the original question or better yet, create a new one. If my comments answered your original question, I'll convert them to an answer

Comment: Yes It worked after changing Output format to REL. Now Again when i tried to get the content using Content Service API, it is rendering tcdl tags instead of component content.